# objc_exception_throw, can't get any clue after added All Exceptions Breakpoint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, debugging

I started learning swift programming a few months ago, I'm trying make a simple livescore app using web service. I tried to debug my application using All Exceptions breakpoint, and it catched "*objc_exception_throw*", then i typed po $arg1 to see the human-readable version of the error, but i've no idea how to solve this error. This is the code in my controller, i've put all function to change the UI inside main thread, but I still get this error.Any suggestion will be appreciation.

```
 session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { ( data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        // Memastikan mendapatkan response OK
        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if httpStatus?.statusCode == 200
            {
            if (data?.count == 59)
                {
                DispatchQueue.main.sync
                {
                    self.displayLabel(Message: "No Data Available")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
                else if data?.count != 0
                        {
                    if let jsonDictionary = NetworkService.parseMultipleArrayJSON(data) {
                        let topTeam4Goal = jsonDictionary[0] as! [String: Any]
                        let topTeam4Red = jsonDictionary[1] as! [String: Any]
                        let topTeam4Yellow = jsonDictionary[2] as! [String: Any]

                        let topTeam4GoalDictionaries = topTeam4Goal["topGoalTeam"] as! [[String: Any]]
                        let topTeam4RedDictionaries = topTeam4Red["topRedTeam"] as! [[String: Any]]
                        let topTeam4YellowDictionaries = topTeam4Yellow["topYellowTeam"] as! [[String: Any]]

                        for topTeamGoalDictionary in topTeam4GoalDictionaries {
                            let newTopGoal = Team(topTeamGoalDictionary: topTeamGoalDictionary)
                            self.topGoal.append(newTopGoal)
                        }
                        self.sectionData[0] = self.topGoal;

                        for topTeamRedDictionary in topTeam4RedDictionaries {
                            let newTopRed = Team(topTeamRedDictonary: topTeamRedDictionary)
                            self.topRed.append(newTopRed)

                        }

                        self.sectionData[1] = self.topRed


                        for topTeamYellowDictionary in topTeam4YellowDictionaries {
                            let newTopYellow = Team(topTeamYellowDictionary: topTeamYellowDictionary)
                            self.topYellow.append(newTopYellow)
                        }

                        self.sectionData[2] = self.topYellow

                        DispatchQueue.main.sync
                        {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                        refreshControl.endRefreshing()

                    }
            }
        }
            else
        {
            //print("error httpstatus code is :", httpStatus?.statusCode as Any)
            DispatchQueue.main.sync{
                if(httpStatus != nil && httpStatus?.statusCode.description != "500") {
                    self.showAlert(Message: (httpStatus?.statusCode.description)!)
                }
            }
            refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }

    }).resume()
```

[Breakpoint Screenshot, Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSmZ4.jpg)

Comment: All UI work must be done on the main queue, including updating the refresh control.

Comment: OMG, thanks for your answer. It's solved.